# How to minify HTML with Webpack mix (not Laravel Elixir)

Tags: html, laravel, minify, laravel-mix

I use Laravel 6 and I want to minify my HTML with Webpack mix! Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean the output of the blade templates? These don't go through mix, you would have to write your own renderer for this..

Comment: Yes, I mean the output of the blades. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify-html-webpack-plugin) that can minimize the HTML with HTMLMinifier for all source directory files and copy into destinations directory during the Webpack build.